# How do I resolve the no-restricted-syntax from eslinter in JavaScript ?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

I am using ESLint in my project and am using the airbnb style guide. The following piece of code in my program is giving me a linting issue. I am working on ES6. It's telling me to avoid using for-in here. What would be a better alternative as per ES6 standards ?

```
function solveRole (i18nData) {
  entries = {};

    for (const property in i18nData) {
    entries[property] = i18nData[property];
  }
}
```

Comment: [no-restricted-syntax RULE](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-syntax) AND to solve it, add `/* eslint no-restricted-syntax: ["ForInStatement"] */` at the top of file.

Comment: Is there a way I can use Object.keys to resolve this ? I am looking at replacing the for-in here.

Comment: `Object.keys(i18nData).forEach(function (property) {`

Answer (score 9):

There's no need to iterate over the keys using either a `for-in` loop or `Object.keys(...).forEach` as all you are doing is assigning all properties of one object to another.

Try this:

```
const entries = Object.assign({}, i18nData)
```